# get smarty array value in php {php}

Tags: php, smarty

here is my dilemma
I have 2 variables, 1 is an array and one is not.
`{$variable1}` value is "hello";
`{sp}` value is a multi dimensional array.
I use

```
{php}$xid = $smart->get_template_vars('variable1');{/php}
```

to assign the variable $xid the value hello.
however when I use the same code :

```
{php}$sparray = $smart->get_template_vars('sp');{/php}
```

this breaks the code. so the page doesn't load. any suggestions ?
p.s: I am trying to get the value of {sp.options.colors} inside the {php} tags

if I use {sp.options.colors} it returns "red" for example. 
anyway  I can get the value inside php ?

Comment: YOU ARE THE 210,000th PERSON TO TAG A QUESTION WITH PHP! CONGRATS!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out : 
in smarty use `$sparray = $this->get_template_vars('sp');`
and in php put: `$sparray[options][colors];`